# NASM assembly byte boundary alignment

Tags: assembly, nasm

everyone,

I am a newbie on learning NASM assembly language. From my textbook, one of the sample code is as following:

```
ORG 0100H
JMP start
value DW 0
csmsg DB 13,10, 'CS (in hex) = ', '$'
dsmsg DB 13,10, 'DS (in hex) = ', '$'
esmsg DB 13,10, 'ES (in hex) = ', '$'
ssmsg DB 13,10, 'SS (in hex) = ', '$'
spmsg DB 13,10, 'SP (in hex) = ', '$'
;
%include "../mymacro/showbyte.mac"
;
start:
    MOV [value], CS
    MOV DX, csmsg
    CALL show
;
    MOV [value], DS
    MOV DX, dsmsg
    CALL show
;
    MOV [value], ES
    MOV DX, esmsg
    CALL show
;
    MOV [value], SS
    MOV DX, ssmsg
    CALL show
;
    MOV [value], SP
    MOV DX, spmsg
    CALL show
;
    MOV AX, 4c00H
    INT 21H
show:
    MOV AH,09H
    INT 21H
    showbyte value+1;
    showbyte value
    RET
```

My question is that I don't know what does the following line of the code do...
and why do we need to do it this way:

```
csmsg DB 13,10, 'CS (in hex) = ', '$'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DOS, strings are terminated with a dollar sign - $ instead of a NULL.  13 is the ASCII code for return and 10 is the ASCII code new line.